# Python converting letter to ASCII using ord

Tags: python, ord

I am trying to do some coursework but I have hit a wall. I am trying to write a function that takes a letter and a digit as the inputs, and returns the letter shifted key positions to the right in the alphabet.
This is what I have so far:

```
def code_char(c,key):
    letter=input("Enter letter to be moved")
    shift=int(input("Enter degree of shift"))
    letter=ord(letter)    

    if letter>=65 and letter <=90: 
          letter=letter+shift
          while letter>90:
                  letter=letter-26

    elif letter>=97 and letter <=122:
          letter=letter+shift
          while letter>122:
                  letter=letter-26

    letter=chr(letter)
    print(letter)

code_char("",0)
```

The problem is the letter=ord(letter) as I keep getting TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but list found. I have tried different variations.
I need to convert the input 'letter' into ASCII.

Comment: The problem is that `letter` will contain a **new line `\n`** as well. You should use `.strip()` on it...

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine on my machine (once I corrected the indentation, that is). Are you sure this is the code you're running? Also, what are you typing into the prompts that `input` creates?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, but according to `input`'s documentation, "The trailing newline is stripped." so you shouldn't have to do that yourself.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `input` behaves very differently between 2.7 and 3.X.

Comment: @Kevin The error he is getting getting a list where he should find a length 1 str is because he is using a pre-auto-strip input

Comment: Patrick check all the formatting edits I did, the code is way cleaner now.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I wrote an answer based on your comment, if you want to write it youself leave a comment in my answer and I'll remove it.

Comment: @Adirio, I don't understand. What's a "pre-auto-strip input"? Are you saying "He's using the value before the newline is stripped"? But that's impossible because `input` strips it before it returns it. Are you saying "he's using a version of Python that is older, and whose `input` doesn't auto-strip newlines"? What version is that, specifically?

Comment: @Adirio your code is correct, thank you it was the strip() that was missing. I am using python 3.6.0

Comment: I highly doubt that `strip` helped. The code in your question already works fine.

Comment: When using Python 3.6 the strip should not be necesary as Kevin suggests: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Why are you calling `input` inside `code_char`? Shouldn't you be using the `c` and `key` args?

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I may agree that the first edit of the comment may be two much of an edit, but at least you could have maintained the indentation edit,  because, as suggested by the error, its a SO formatting typo, not a actual indentation bug.

Comment: @Adirio I read the link you shared but I really do not understand, whatever variation of the input I use I still get the same error message that I did before, I have tried on previous versions of python and still it only works with .strip().

Comment: The link I provided is from Python 3.6 and sais: _If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (**stripping a trailing newline**), and returns that._ This means that it already does the `.strip()` automatically. Older versions didn't use to do this automatically and that's the reason you may need to use it to avoid the error.

Answer (score -4):

As suggested by Willem in the OP comments, `input()` is giving you a `str` containing the letter and the **new-line char `\n`**, use `.strip()` to solve it if you are using an old Python version:

```
def code_char():
    letter = ord(input("Enter letter to be moved").strip())
    shift = int(input("Enter degree of shift"))

    if (letter >= 65) and (letter <= 90):
        letter += shift
        while (letter > 90):
            letter -= 26
    elif (letter >= 97) and (letter <= 122):
        letter += shift
        while letter > 122:
            letter -= 26

    print(chr(letter))

code_char()
```

New Python versions (e.g. 3.6.0) should not need the `.strip()` part, being your code after the formatting edit I did working perfectly:

```
def code_char():
    letter = ord(input("Enter letter to be moved"))
    shift = int(input("Enter degree of shift"))

    if (letter >= 65) and (letter <= 90):
        letter += shift
        while (letter > 90):
            letter -= 26
    elif (letter >= 97) and (letter <= 122):
        letter += shift
        while letter > 122:
            letter -= 26

    print(chr(letter))

code_char()
```

Comment: I am using python version 3.6.0

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: `input` does not return a list in 3.X. It might return a list in 2.7, but only if the user entered something absurd like `["A"]`. If `input` did return a list, then calling `strip()` on it would cause a crash because `strip` is not a valid method for lists. If you're thinking "I misspoke, I meant `input` is returning a _string_ containing the letter and the new-line char", that's also wrong. `input` strips the newline for you automatically.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah I was talking about a `str`, and yes, I know in 3.X it auto-strip's but the answer was given before he said his Python version and without any tag that should point towards that version. Completed the answer with Python3 option

Comment: Downvoters: this answer is right, downvoting for no reason just makes this answer (the only one) seem to be incorrect, which it's not.

Comment: @Adirio I have copied your code exactly into python and I still get the error message TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Comment: @PatrickAsindi You have copied the code without `.strip()` in Python 3.6 and it doesn't work?

Comment: @Adirio the problem was the fact I was asking the user for information where I should be just been writing a function also, the was using space before inputting. It worked when I just used letter=ord(c). Thank you for your help but at the end of the day I was just overthinking things.